# Provide a combinatorial proof for the following identitiy

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

Give a combinatorial proof that

$k$ $n \choose k$ = $n$$n-1 \choose k-1$

Comment: One begins by "trying"; referring to your text, lecture notes, examples, and to definitions. One does not first begin by posting to mse hoping others do your work for you. Please include more context in your question. In what course does this question arise? What is its source? What have you tried, and/or add what you think might be relevant to solving this.

Comment: These are the kind of questions that abuse the purpose of this site.  Would you please take the tour of the site, and while you are at it, please read items listed [below "Asking"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Comment: Will do thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We count committees of size $k$ with a chairperson selected from a group with $n$ people.

The left hand side counts the number of ways we can select a committee of $k$ people from a group of $n$ people, then select one of those $k$ people to be the chairperson.

The right hand side counts the number of ways we can choose one of the $n$ people to be the chairperson, then select the remaining $k - 1$ members of the committee from the remaining $n - 1$ people.